# Boot issues - GPU pci config reset

Tags: kali-linux, configuration, gpu, pci

I have some issue to boot to Kali since i reboot the computer. I don't think i install some software, but i may be have run apt-get update since the last success boot.

With the kernel 4.9.0-Kali4-amd64, the system fails booting with the following message:

> [ powerplay ] VBIOS did not find boot engine clock value in dependency
>   table. Using Memory DPM level 0!

In recovery mode the system boot stop progressing at the following step:

> admgpu 0000:0a:00.0: GPU pci config reset

I have a multi boot with windows 10 who is still working.
The system is running on a HP laptop with intel i5-5200 cpu and ADM R5 m255 GPU

Any clue how i can solve my boot issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the package `laptop-mode-tools` installed?

If so, you might want to try to `apt remove` it.